# Intel (9700k) VS AMD (3700x) for a Machine Learning build

Tags: processor

I'm building a rig over at my workplace for running/training machine learning models. Currently we are building chatbots using Rasa framework, some tensorflow neural networks and possibly CNN's and RNN's in near future.

Build includes

- RAM: 32 gigs of DDR4 3000MHZ
- Storage: 250gigs SSD + 2TB HDD
- GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2070 Super
- PSU: 650 Watt Corsair TXM

and all other necessary peripherals.

The problem is that we cannot to pick between Intel and AMD. Rasa framework uses models that are not too deep and hence train faster on CPU while other cases are faster on GPU. So both are equally important for us to work as fast as they can within out budget.

Could someone please advice as to which CPU is better for machine learning between 9700k and 3700x? Is 9700k faster in ML than 3700x? Are there some libraries/software that would favor Intel over AMD?

Comment: "Are there some libraries/software that would favor Intel over AMD?" -- The main reason that one CPU may be favoured over the other is if a library uses an extension that one CPU has and the other doesn't. [AMD Ryzen 7 3700X Extensions](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/ryzen_7/3700x#Features), [Intel i7-9700K Extensions](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i7/i7-9700k#Features).

Comment: Without checking any benchmarks, I can see that the AMD Ryzen 7 supports more threads and has a bigger cache, so it will probably outperform the i7-9700K in most multi-threaded workloads.